JMeter - Write captured values into a file
I have 2 jmx scripts with a request each. From the response of JMX-1, a value is to be captured. This is done via a regular expression extractor. Now, the value is to be written to a file.
This file is to be sent as an input to JMX-2.
Could you please let me know the procedure to do this?
Regards,
I have used a JSR223 sampler. Write the results into a CSV file using groovy functions. However, I feel this could become an issue with increase in load (>1 Thread).
Is there an optimized way to do this?

If you use scripting for writing something into the same file with multiple threads it will result into a race condition and cause data corruption and/or loss.
Consider switching to Flexible File Writer instead
Flexible File Writer doesn't come with JMeter, you can install it using JMeter Plugins Manager
